# How to get Column (the gnu/linux utility) for Windows (MINGW)?

Tags: windows, mingw

MINGW does not come with the "column" utility. I want to be able to do something like:

`cat file.txt | column -t`

Is there a way I can install just that utility for Windows? Preferably a single file, rather than installing an entire suite like Cygwin.